# linux terminal:how to search path in windows pc?

Tags: windows, linux, terminal, path

i'm newbie in linux, and i work with linux terminal to control another linux pc(client).

Beside that, i have some permition to access windows pc. They give me some IP address, user, and password.

but i have some problem during open some file use php. the owner of windows pc just give me a phisycal file location to open aome DB file. actually i need to open that DB from `path`.

how do i do to search path and file use teminal?

Comment: WTF is "linux terminal"? Your question is very unclear. Also accessing databases using file i/o across a network is going to cause problems - particulalry for a web application

Answer (score 2):

Something not entirely unlike

```
mkdir /mnt/foo
mount -t cifs -o /somepath/smbcred //123.45.6.7/share /mnt/foo
find /mnt/foo -name DB.php.or.whatever
```

where smbcred is a file that you create which contains

```
username=fred
password=jkgh%3ff-b
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to mount a windows share, check the smbmount man page:

man smbmount

Comment: how to use smb if i just have ip address, and user and password to access DB file?

Comment: upvoted RedGrittyBrick's answer, he has it laid out perfectly